# My home-network disconnect every few minutes and then reconnected

Tags: router, home-networking, nas

reupload topology,hope you can understand

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|NETWORK TOPOLOGY|                                           Use Vlan        |
+----------------+                                          +--------+       |
|                                                           |        |       |
|                          +--------------------------------+ TV Box |       |
|                          |  +----------------+            |        |       |
|                          |  |                |            +--------+       |
|                 +---------------------+      |                             |
|                 |        +  +         |      |                             |
|   +--------------+WAN    1  2  3  4   |      |         +-----------+       |
|   |             |              +      |      |         |           |       |
|   |             +---------------------+      +---------+ Media Box |       |
|   |             NETGEAR Router |                       |           |       |
|   |                            +---------+             +-----------+       |
|   |                                      |                                 |
|   |       +----------------------------------+                             |
|   |       |                              +   |                             |
|   |       |  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   |                             |
|   |       |  +   +   +                       |                             |
|   |       +----------------------------------+                +-------+    |
|   |          |   |   |   Switch                               |       |    |
|   |          |   |   +----------------------------------------+  NAS  |    |
|   |          |   +---------------------------------+          |       |    |
|   |          +--------------------+                |          +-------+    |
|   +------------------+            |                |                       |
|                      |            |                |          +------+     |
|                +------------------------+          |          |      |     |
|                |     +            +     |          +----------+  AP  |     |
|                |     1            2     |                     |      |     |
|                |  internet      IPTV    |                     +------+     |
|                |   output      output   |                                  |
|                +------------------------+                                  |
|                       Fiber router                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

router,TvBox and MediaBox is at front of my Tv wall,where there has two 
network cable port on the wall connect to weak(Electric) box.
switch and fiber router is in weak box.

the problem is Tvbox and Mediabox lost connect every few minute and reconnect.just happened when I watch a movie or watch TV,it stop for a while and come back.

thx! sorry for my terrible english..

Comment: Add the device make and models to the question. The topology pic is chicken scratch, please reupload that in paint, or anything that will be legible.